# How can I fix this simple C overflow?

Tags: c

I'm very new to this. I am trying to re-write this code in order to remove the buffer overflow that is picked up in lines 12 + 19.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE (1024)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* inBuf;
  char* outBuf;
  char* fmt = "the winner is: %s";

  inBuf = (char*) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
  if (inBuf == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  read(0, inBuf, BUF_SIZE);
  outBuf = (char*) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
  if (outBuf == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  sprintf(outBuf, fmt, inBuf);
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", outBuf);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", outBuf);
  free(inBuf);
  free(outBuf);
}
```

If someone could provide some insight on the best way to approach this? would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: C <> C++. This is not C++ code. Please do not randomly add tags because they seem familiar. Tags have specific meaning and relevance here. If you're not clear on which language you're writing code, you should remove your fingers from the keyboard and figure that out before trying to do anything else. Also, if you're *trying to figure out* how to fix this issue, you should have some details about how you've attempted to do so. This reads like a homework assignment that you're trying to get us to answer for you. How do you think you should proceed?

Comment: You are reading BUF_SIZE characters and then writing BUF_SIZE + 15 into outbuf.  Also, you are not checking the result of read.

Comment: Also, `read` does not produce a valid C string. That is, it does not add a NUL terminator for you. Do that yourself: `r = read(0, inBuf, BUF_SIZE-1); inBuf[r] = '\0';`. Note that this leaves a newline character at the end of the string.

Comment: If you cannot malloc outBuf, then it will return without freeing the inBuf. Actually it rarely happen I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the `read` function to read user input, you're reading raw bytes as opposed to a string.  So what it read in doesn't include a null terminating byte, so you don't have a null terminated string since the buffer returned by `malloc` is uninitialized.

Use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, which returns a buffer initialized to all zeros.

```
inBuf = calloc(BUF_SIZE + 1, 1);
```

Note that this leaves an extra byte for a terminating null character.

You should also be checking the return value of `read` for an error, and you shoudn't cast the return value of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Your output buffer size is also too small.  It should be at least the size of the input string plus the format string.

```
outBuf = (char*) malloc(BUF_SIZE + 1 + strlen(fmt));
```

Comment: Should allocated `BUF_SIZE+1`, or manually write a null terminator. Also you need to address overflow caused by `sprintf` format string